# how to find out whole function of a class in java script

Tags: javascript, kotlin, webview, android-webview

I'm sending a class to my site using android web view just like this:
`webView.addJavascriptInterface(data, "info")`I wanted to know is there any way that I find out what functions and what variables are there in info class on the web side?
for example, if my data class be like this:

```
class Data(){
     val name = ""
     val family = ""
     fun getName():String = name
     fun getFamily():String = family
}
```

what javascript code I should use to understand the info class has two variables name and family?
currently, my web side is just like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
</head>
<body>


<script>
document.write(info.getName());
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

and using that I can access to name variable which is passed by android side,
how can I understand also there is a getFamily function too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use a built-in method of javascript you can get the whole method of an object `object.keys(name_of_object)`.

for example, in your case, it would be like this

```
document.write(object.keys(info));
```

and It will print
`getName()` and `getFamily()`